# big trouble with javascript

Tags: images

I have some js scripts that are working on my site but I have found that some of the images are not showing up. I only have this issue with WordPress. So I have a pause button that shows as it's supposed to. When you press the button, it pauses the script as it's supposed to. When this happens, a new image is added to replace the pause button. The image gets inserted into the page. So it looks like this when it's playing

```
 <img id="pauseplay" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme/images/pause.png" alt="">
```

When I press the pause button, it changes to this

```
 <img id="pauseplay" src="images/play.png" alt="">
```

obviously this is a problem with absolute to relative links but I don't know how to fix it.
Why don't relative links work in WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

Relative URLs work nicely in wordpress, which is the reason for your failures. In general never use relative URLs for resources as they will most likely fail when a site is using "pretty permalinks".

Best thing for what you are doing is to "group" the graphical resources and styling in a CSS (in which resources are relative to the CSS file and not the HTML URL).

The JS alternative is to store the root of the site/theme/plugin in a JS variable and use it to construct the URL. Followin code is to take site root into consideration, but you most likely will want theme or plugin root.

```
<script>
  var homeurl = '<?php echo home_url()?>';
.....
  pauseImage = homeurl+"images/play.png"; // url to your play image
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try a backslash '/' in front of  'images/play.png'

so the url will look like this: '/images/play.png'

(assuming your images directory is in the root of your site)